# How to use public key to validate JWT Token using vertx

Tags: java, kotlin, jwt, vert.x, onelogin

I am using Vertx with Kotlin and want to authenticate a JWT Token.

I have the public key in Json Web Key file from One Login.

```
{   "keys": [
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "kid": "JRcO4nxs5jgc8YdN7I2hLO4V_ql1bdoiMXmcYgHm4Hs",
  "n": "z8fZsz...Something..GHSTAoQw",
  "e": "AQAB"
}   ] }
```

How can I use the above mentioned public key in Json Web Key file to authenticate if a JWT Token is valid?

The class/method I am using is JWTAuth.create(vertx, config)

```
var config = JWTAuthOptions(
                pubSecKeys = listOf(PubSecKeyOptions(
                    algorithm = "RS256",
                    publicKey = "<Value Copied from above json's 'n' field>")))


  var provider = JWTAuth.create(myvertx, config)
```

Above line throws an exception saying that 
RuntimeException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=71, too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to above problem. So, if you have a 'certs' url which returns Json Web Key file then you can create a java.security.PublicKey object out of it which can be used with PubSecKeyOptions object.

You need to read the values of keys 'n' and 'e' , the 'n' is the called modulus and 'e' is called exponent. Now, you can get a valid JWTAuthOptions object as follows;

```
val n = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(nValue.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
val e = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(eValue.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
val thePublicKeyINeeded: PublicKey= =KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA).generatePublic(RSAPublicKeySpec(n, e))        


val encodedBase64PublicKey:String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(thePublicKeyINeeded.encoded)
    var config = JWTAuthOptions(
                pubSecKeys = listOf(PubSecKeyOptions(
                    algorithm = "RS256",
                    publicKey = encodedBase64PublicKey)))
```